# udisks FilesystemUnmount appears to not exist when calling from python

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to unmount a filesystem that I mounted using FilesystemMount, but I keep getting UnknownMethod exceptions.  I've verified that I can call the method on the Device interface via D-Feet, but trying to do it via dbus directly doesn't appear to work at all.  I've tried using the following arguments:

- ''
- None
- []
- ['']

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks', '/dev/fd0')
dev = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device')
dev.FilesystemUnmount(['force'])
```

Exception:

`dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "FilesystemUmount" with signature "as" on interface "org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device" doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is that FilesystemUnmount will only take an ObjectPath that udisks handed out.  So by adding a check for that and then looking it up I got it to work.  See the code below.

```
import dbus

path = '/dev/fd0'

bus = dbus.SystemBus()

if not isinstance(path, dbus.ObjectPath):
    manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks',
                                 '/org/freedesktop/UDisks')
    manager = dbus.Interface(manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')
    path = manager.FindDeviceByDeviceFile(path)

proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks', path)
dev = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device')
dev.FilesystemUnmount('')
```